# See PHP log files in eclipse with link to source code

Tags: php, eclipse, logging, console, stack-trace

I'm looking for a solution to see the log files (currently from php code) in eclipse AND to be able to click on a line of the stacktrace that will open the source file concerned by the stacktrace.

For example, if the log file contains a line like this: 
`E:\PROGRAM\wamp\www\QUAL\plugins\tctools\inc\commondb.class.php:27 userErrorHandlerNormal()`

I'd like to be able to click on this line and eclipse should open file `commondb.class.php`at `line 27`.

Could really save a lot of time !!!

Any idea is welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to run the browser in DEBUG mode using the Zend Studio browser toolbar. So, the server errors becomes cliquable.